# How to authorize via Google on a web site for selected domains (mails)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google, oauth

I'm interested in the question: is it possible to configure the Google OAuth application so that the site can only be entered from certain domains (mails)?

Perhaps there is functionality on the Google OAuth side to prohibit login and registration on the site for everyone (White List for authorization) The site is powered by WordPress

I will be glad to any advice and help.

It is necessary to restrict users who can log in via Google on the WordPress site

*Example: A WordPress site with authorization via Google, you need to make it possible to skip only those domains (mails) that are added to the list of allowed authorizations, for example - mail@example.com (Business accounts) and reject others - mail@gmail.com*

Comment: Please don't cross post. You already got responses [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78218416/how-to-authorize-via-google-on-a-web-site-for-selected-domains-mails)  and the question is not really on topic here.